# Break on exception in Chrome using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

In order to investigate some Selenium test failures I would like to automatically enable the [pause on exception feature in the Chrome Devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/automatically-pause-on-any-exception) when running the tests.

There is the `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` command line option for automatically opening the DevTools pane which I am already using but apparently there is no CLI option/parameter for the autopause feature I am looking for.

What I came across though is the [`Debugger.setPauseOnExceptions` Chrome Devtools Protocol command](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Debugger#method-setPauseOnExceptions) which I tried activating using [`execute_cdp_cmd`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=cdp#selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_cdp_cmd)(I am using Selenium for Python):

```py
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Debugger.setPauseOnExceptions", {"state": "all"})
```

Unfortunately, even when the tab is open (including the DevTools pane) I am getting

```
unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Debugger agent is not enabled"}
```

**What am I doing wrong or is there some other way (preferably a reliable and portable way, please no macro stuff) I could use?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to enable the debugger before the command:

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Debugger.enable", {})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Debugger.setPauseOnExceptions", {"state": "all"})
```

Comment: Apparently it works but only after I have navigated to a page but because of this it does not work for script which are executed right after page init (`drive.get()` is async). Also it is not visible in the DevTools that it has been activated.