# Debugger.setPauseOnExceptions for Selenium debugging not working

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-devtools-protocol

To investigate Selenium test failures due to Javascript errors (in Google Chrome) I am running the tests locally (non-headless-ly) with the `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` command line option for Chrome in combination with the [`Debugger.setPauseOnExceptions` Chrome Devtools Protocol command](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Debugger#method-setPauseOnExceptions) (see also [Break on exception in Chrome using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56964779/2261442)).

Apparently this does not work (any more), a small test case in Selenium for Python:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.chrome.options.Options()

options.add_argument('--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
  options=options,
  service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=chromedriver.log"]
)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

page = """
<html>
   <head><title>Test</title></head>
   <body>
    <script>
      function errorTest() {
        setTimeout(() => alert('It should pause before me!'), 1000)
        throw new Error('Foobar')
      }
    </script>
    <button id="btn" onclick="errorTest()">Click me</button>
   </body>
</html>
"""

driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + page)

wait.until(
  EC.title_contains("Test"),
  "Page did not load"
)

driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Debugger.enable", {})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Debugger.setPauseOnExceptions", {"state": "all"})

driver.find_element_by_id("btn").click()
```

According to `chromedriver.log` the CDP commands seem to be accepted properly. Is there something I missed?

Current (stable) Selenium client (3.141.0) on Python 3.8 and current Google Chrome (83).

Comment: Could be a bug in Chrome. Try [bisecting](https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py) it.

Comment: @wOxxOm Indeed was a bug (or rather a workaround for a bug which got fixed in the meantime). I reported it at http://crbug.com/1099671 and it was fixed in 86.0.4198.0 (currently in the Canary channel).